# How to use Object.defineProperties?

Tags: javascript

everyone, I read Professional.JavaScript.for.Web.Developers.3rd.Edition recently. Here's the code I learn from it. However, the output is different from the book I read. When I run the code below, `book.edition is 1`, `book._year` is 2004 and `book.year` is 2004. What happen?What's wrong with my code?

```
var book = {};

Object.defineProperties(book, {
  _year: {
    value: 2004
  },
  edition: {
    value: 1
  },

  year: {
    get: function() {
      return this._year;
    },

    set: function(newValue) {
      if (newValue > 2004) {
        this._year = newValue;
        this.edition += newValue - 2004;
      }
    }
  }
});

book.year = 2005;
console.log(book.edition);
console.log(book._year);
console.log(book.year);
```

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: That looks like the right output to me. `book._year` just gets the variable directly and `book.year` is a getter function which returns `_year` so they should both return the same value

Comment: @Jayce444 they should be returning 2005 instead of 2004, and `edition` should be 2.

Answer (score 3):

Properties `_year` and `edition` of your object should be defined as writable. Otherwise it's useless to redefine them inside year's setter.

```js
var book = {};

Object.defineProperties(book, {
  _year: {
    value: 2004,
    writable:true
  },
  edition: {
    value: 1,
    writable:true
  },

  year: {
    
    get: function() {
      return this._year;
    },

    set: function(newValue) {
      
      if (newValue > 2004) {
        this._year = newValue;
        this.edition += newValue - 2004;
      }
    }
  }
});


console.log(book.edition);
console.log(book.year);
book.year=2005;
console.log(book.edition);
console.log(book.year);
```